# IBM (ISAM) , Single Sign-on and a PHP Web App

Tags: php, web-applications, active-directory, single-sign-on, isam

I need some guidance regarding "single sign-on" and "ibm security verify access v10". I am not particularly a programmer but based on the task given to me i created a simple PHP based web app that uses html form (username/password) and authenticates users against "traditional microsoft active directory" and i used "xampp apache web server" and sometimes "IIS web server".

Now i am trying to do is to give my web app single sign-on using ibm security verify access but i am getting confused and lost here because it's not easy to find information related to this exact configuration. One concept that might be useful is i think 'Forms Single Sign-on" but I can't find out a clear configuration example so i can compare and implement. I need help with this i.e what is the best SSO option based on my situation and how or where i can find se material e.g how to implement forms sso in this situation. I am still in training phase and merely  month and a half in so most of its overwhelming.

My setup that i have right now is:

1: one VM for Security Verify Access console

2: one VM which runs windows server 2016 amd active directory where i have created some users

3: one VM running same OS and Security Directory Server as my external LDAP

4: A simple php HTML form based web app

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement on premise integration with IBM Security Verify, if yes check out following document
[IBM security verify with AD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCT62/com.ibm.iamservice.doc/concepts/c_winad_identity_provider.html)

This is just to understand what SSO is how to integrate with SAML & how everything works.
[How SSO works with SAML](https://www.varonis.com/blog/what-is-saml/)

Hope this get you started on path

Comment: I have already integrated ISAM to my active directory and my php app authenticates users against this active directory and now i wanted to implement SSO using this particular setup with AD and my web app. My web app uses HTML form based authentication so i thought forms SSO concept might work but I can't find anh proper document that explains in detail on how to implement that on ISAM.

Comment: I'll look into the links that you just shared

Comment: Also i think "ibm security verify" and "ibm security verify access (also known as ISAM/Tivoli)" are two different products